# qooxdoo htmlarea pasteHTML on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, qooxdoo

I'm trying to insert an image into a HTMLarea, it's working OK but on IE, the `pasteHTML` on `qx.bom.htmlarea.manager.Commmand.js:950` is falling by the catch, with no message. If I comment the try catch, IE launch a javascript error with no message.

If you want to try yourself, go to http://efexam.com/app, then open Questions Database, Create New Question, tab Edition and button insert image. After a correct upload, server returns the url for the new image, then IE fails to add the `img` tag to the embedded `HTMLArea`.

Answer (score 1):

this seems to be a bug in the HtmlArea. Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org so we can track this issue.

Thanks for the info!

Regards,
  Alex